# How can I force pipenv to run on python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, pip, pipenv

It's my first question so be kind.

I have python 3.8 as the base on my machine (Linux Mint), and I need to run someone else's code from python 3.6

I ran

```
 pipenv --python 3.6.15 shell
```

and then
pipenv --python 3.6.15 update
followed by

```
 pipenv --python 3.6.15 install
```

and that failed due to missing dependencies, but it keeps referencing python 3.8:

```
pipenv --python 3.6.15 check

Checking PEP 508 requirements...
Passed!
Checking installed package safety...
Failed parsing JSON results:
ERROR: Pipenv encountered a problem and had to exit.
ERROR TEXT: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kieran/.pyenv/versions/3.6.15/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/home/kieran/.pyenv/versions/3.6.15/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/kieran/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/patched/safety/__main__.py", line 47, in <module>
    from pipenv.patched.safety.cli import cli
  File "/home/kieran/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/__init__.py", line 59, in <module>
    from .cli import cli
  File "/home/kieran/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/cli/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .command import cli  # noqa
  File "/home/kieran/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/cli/command.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pipenv.cli.options import (
  File "/home/kieran/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/cli/options.py", line 3, in <module>
    from pipenv.project import Project
  File "/home/kieran/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/project.py", line 2
    from __future__ import annotations
```

I just want an environment to run under python 3.6 and tell pipenv not to reference 3.8 t all. How do I do that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Pyenv** is a tool used to manage different Python versions. With this tool you can:

- Install several Python versions.
- Easily switch between multiple versions of Python
- Set/change the global(default) Python version in your computer.
- Set/change a Python version locally for a project.
- Create and manage virtual environments.

To select a Pyenv-installed Python as the version to use, run one of the following commands:

**pyenv shell**  -- select just for current shell session

**pyenv local**  -- automatically select whenever you are in the current directory (or its subdirectories)

**pyenv global**  -- select globally for your user account

Now let’s take a look at the possible Python versions that you can install through Pyenv, executing:

```
pyenv install --list
```

You will see a large list of Python versions. You can pick one to install it, let’s say 3.9.1:

```
pyenv install 3.9.1
```

You can run that command with any version that you want to have installed on your computer. To see all the installed versions, just run:

```
pyenv versions
```

Also, you can set the global version that you want to use in your system, this will be the default one. For example, if you have already installed 3.8.8, you can set it as the global version running:

```
pyenv global 3.8.8
```

You can change that, of course, by executing the command again with the desired installed version. If you want to check your global version, just run:

```
python -V
```

With Pyenv, you can have a global and a local version for each project. To set a local version, go to the project folder in the terminal:

```
cd ~/path/to/the/project/folder
```

And set the local version, for example, 3.9.1:

```
pyenv local 3.9.1
```

This will create a `.python-version` file in the folder indicating the current local Python version for the project. Also, if you run `python -V` in that folder, you will see the local version, and not the global one.

So, to sum up, you have the following useful commands at your disposal:

- `pyenv install --list` to see the available Python versions you can install.
- `pyenv versions` to see the installed Python versions.
- `pyenv global <Python version>` to set an installed Python version as global.
- `pyenv local <Python version>` to set an installed Python version for a given project folder.
- `pyenv uninstall <Python version>` to uninstall an already installed Python version.

**Pipenv** is a tool used to manage the required packages in a Python project. With this tool you can:

- Automatically create or delete a virtual environment.
- Install, uninstall and update packages maintaining the desired versions.
- Set up very quickly a working Python environment.
- Have a list of the installed packages and the corresponding version.

`pipenv install` to create a virtual environment.

`pipenv install --python <Python version>` to create a virtual environment indicating the desired Python version (that you have installed using Pyenv).

`pipenv --rm` to delete the current virtual environment.

`pipenv shell` to activate the created virtual environment.

`exit` to deactivate an already activated virtual environment.

`pipenv install <package name>` to install the latest version of the package under the [packages] section.

`pipenv install <package name>==<package version>` to install a specified version of a package, under the `[packages]` section.

`pipenv update <package name>` to update a version of a package(upgrade or downgrade) to the one that you have previously specified in the Pipfile.

Adding `--dev` to the previous commands, Pipenv will do the same but under the [dev-packages] section.

`pipenv uninstall <package name>` to uninstall a package.

Pyenv is used to manage different Python versions, whereas Pipenv is used to manage Python packages.

ref: https://www.rootstrap.com/blog/how-to-manage-your-python-projects-with-pipenv-pyenv/

Comment: Baris thank you for the explanation. However it doesn't address that I have python 3.6.15 set in my Pipfile but still 'pipenv check' calls packages from python3.8 - how do i get rid of those?

Comment: Can you create virtual environmend use this `pipenv install --python 3.6.15` and activate the created virtual environment with `pipenv shell`

Comment: in one directory yes I can do this, but if I go to the project directory which has the packages and setup.py and all that,  and run it and then `pipenv update`, I get the errors I was receiving above.

Comment: `  pipenv update
Running $ pipenv lock then $ pipenv sync.
Locking [packages] dependencies...
Building requirements...
Resolving dependencies...
✘ Locking Failed! `

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  {...a bunch of stuff related to python 3.8 the end of which is ....}
  File "/home/kieran/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/project.py", line 2
    from __future__ import annotations
    ^
SyntaxError: future feature annotations is not defined

Comment: I met the same issue, any update status for this?!
i am using the ubuntut22.04 the default python version is 3.10.6, i want to use the python3.6.9 in my env, but met the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I find an alternative way to install the python3.6

The reason that you can not create the env with python3.6 is you do not have the virtualenv for python3.6

use the below cli you can see the virtualenv is for which python

```
virtualenv --version
```

use this way to install the virtualenv for python3.6

```
pip3.6 install virtualenv
```

create the env for python 3.6

you can change the python location by yourself to replace this /usr/local/bin/python3.6

venv is the env folder name, also can change the name by yourself

```
python3.6 -m virtualenv -p /usr/local/bin/python3.6 venv
```

finally, activate the python env

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

This is the current solution I find, still can not find a way with pipenv, but you can try this way if you are urgent to create the env for python 3.6